Primeng customize dropdown items differently from "main" item
I recently installed Primeng.
I'm trying to use p-menubar component aka Menubar, I read on docs that there's the possibility to customize menu items using ng-template but the moment I add "sub-items" (the nested menu items), it applies the same style of the "main" items.
This is what I have right now:
<p-menubar [model]="menuItems">
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item>
        <p style="color: white; padding: 0 10px">{{ item.label }}</p>
    </ng-template>
</p-menubar>

what happens here is that I have a blue background so I set menu items' color to white, unfortunately it applies even to sub-menu, where the background color is white as well, and it makes the text unreadable.
Is there a way to define a second template to customize the submenu items or to keep the style only on the "main" items?
I tried to edit the css but I couldn't achieve the expected result since they're the same element.

For PrimeNG all components can be customized via global styling. 
You just have to make sure, that you use the right classes because PrimeNG applies their styling with multiple nested classes. 
So you should look into your browser and see how the styling is applied with what classes. 
As an example for styling sub-items in a tree you could write it like this:
    .p-tree.p-tree-link .p-tree-container .p-treenode .p-treenode-content {
      padding: .5rem 1.5rem .5rem 2rem;
    }

Do the same thing for your component and apply your styling there.

I tried but unfortunately it's not working, because it's changing even the main menu

Then you would probably need to add another class.
Try looking in the DOM-Tree with your Browser-Tools and look what class each element has.
